# The Stubborn JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox shown in the code below. When the program starts its actionPerformed event fires up immediately causing some null pointer exceptions so I want to start with none of the elements selected. However, for some reason it does not work (it always start with displaying "USD/TRY" whatever I do). Anyone has any idea ?

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"USD/TRY", "EUR/TRY", "GBP/TRY"});

comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1); // doesnt change anything
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(2); // doesnt change anything     
comboBox.setSelectedItem(null); // doesnt change anything
```

UPDATE: Building the combo box like below doesnt change anything either

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(); 

comboBox.addItem("USD/TRY"); 
comboBox.addItem("EUR/TRY"); 
comboBox.addItem("GBP/TRY");
```

Here is the SSCCE:

```
public class MainFrame {

    private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    private IExchangeSource s;

    public MainFrame(final IExchangeSource s) {
        //build gui
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

        comboBox.addItem("USD/TRY");
        comboBox.addItem("EUR/TRY");
        comboBox.addItem("GBP/TRY");

        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1); // doesnt change anything
        //comboBox.setSelectedIndex(2); // doesnt change anything


        JFrame f = new JFrame("Currency Converter");
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        textArea.setName("textarea");
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        this.s = s;

        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String exchange = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();

                s.getData(exchange);
            }
        });

        p.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.add(p);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try loading the String[] after creating the JComboBox?

Comment: Tried and it doesnt work either =/ I updated the question accordingly. thanks

Comment: Having the stack trace of the exception would help. How could you add an ActionListener to a combo box which hasn't been created yet?

Comment: That's what the book says to do.  What layout manager are you using?

Comment: You cannot avoid having a value selected, but even then it's clear your problem lies somewhere else. On what does the actionPerformed handler exactly throw the exception? You should probably assign it later, when proper initialization has been done, or check inside it for the state.

Comment: Its created, the values are there and I can see the values when the GUI starts. The problem is that I can't set the initial value manually (to nothing) for some reason. (I want to do this because I dont want the action listener fire up right at the beginning).

Comment: I've never had this problem. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Gilbert I am writing the SWING code manually. No layout manager is used.

Comment: @Cerrie:  Then that's the problem.  Swing components are interrelated.

Comment: @Viruzzo The Main class inits the Model and the view by using dependency injection by constructors and setters. So when the actionPerformed starts the dependencies are not fully initialized yet (i.e the main method is not finished its task) causing null pointer exceptions when the model tries to access view or vice versa.

Comment: Ah, based on your comment, most people set a blank value as the first (default) value.  Only if a non-blank value is passed to the action listener (user selected something) is the action performed.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I will try using the window builder then and see if anything changes.

Comment: A window builder should not change anything. There is no reason you can't build a GUI manually. In fact it is the approach I recommend since you learn Swing and not the GUI. All you have to do is read the JComboBox API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Combo Boxes` for a working example.

Comment: I didn't say window builder.  You can code Swing components yourself.  I said layout manager.  When you lay out Swing components, you need a layout manager so that Swing knows where the components go.

Comment: It works fine on my test system and selected the correct item initially (when I changed the `comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);` of course). Note: I removed the `IExchangeSource` from your code - so it seems that you did not initialize this correctly (maybe it is null?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your (incomplete) example invokes

```
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

right before becoming visible, canceling any previous setting. Set the desired initial index *before* adding the listener, and don't neglect to start on the [EDT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), as shown in the [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainFrame {

    private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
    public MainFrame() {
        //build gui
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

        comboBox.addItem("USD/TRY");
        comboBox.addItem("EUR/TRY");
        comboBox.addItem("GBP/TRY");

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Currency Converter");
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        textArea.setName("textarea");
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);

        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem() + ": " + e);
            }
        });

        p.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The other answers solved the problems to some extent but there were still some problems however this one completely managed to solve it. I think the lack of invokeLater function for building the frame (i.e: starting on the EDT) was the main problem.

Comment: Thanks for following up; I'm always intrigued by new ways to expose an EDT problem.

Comment: @Cemre, did you ever read the API and the tutorial??? The example from the tutorial uses the EDT properly, thats why I pointed you to the tutorial hours earlier.

Comment: @camickr your link did not work for some reason so I wasnt able to check it at that time sorry about that. I will google and study it now. I am a bit new to swing so I wasnt aware of the importance of the EDT. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Cemre, I didn't give you a link. I expected you to be able to read the API and click on the link yourself. If you are new to Swing then that is all the more reason to actually read the tutorial as was suggested rather than hoping someone writes the code for you.

Comment: @Cemre: camickr's point is well-taken—learning how to navigate the API is a foundational skill. This [index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/) is practically my home page.

Comment: @Cemre _I think the lack of invokeLater function for building the frame (i.e: starting on the EDT) was the main problem_ while a good candidate, I don't really believe that's a problem here. The basic flaw (besides overwriting any initial setting with the setSelected(0) at the very end, as trashgod already noted) in your code was to assume that the getSelectedItem != null in your actionListener: obviously, that assumption is incorrect when nothing is selected which is a perfectly valid state for both the combo and its underlying model.

Answer (score 2):

1) add [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) instead of `ActionListener`, but this `ItemListener` always fired twice events `SELECTED` and `DESELECTED`,

```
  myComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                //some stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

2) your GUI maybe is or isn't created on [EventDispashThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), but in this case doesn't matter, you have to delay this method by wraping into invokeLater(), for example

```
public class MainFrame {
     .
     .
     .

    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.add(p);
    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    f.setVisible(true);
    selectDesiredItem();
}

private void selectDesiredItem() {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        }
    });  
}
```

3) better would be implements [AutoCompete JComboBox / JTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm) for Currency Pairs

4) maybe not important but CcyPairs have got four sides by default

- `Buy BaseCcy`
- `Sell BaseCcy`
- `Buy VariableCcy`
- `Sell VariableCcy`

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I really appreciate it. Although, you second suggestion solved the combo box error, I was still getting null pointer exceptions though.

Comment: @kleopatra happy new year too

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions so far are good.  But sometimes, when things are really convoluted on how Components get constructed, a more direct fix is needed:

1. subclass the JComboBox (or whatever Swing class is firing the events, JList, etc...)
2. add a field, `private boolean fireEvents = false`;  Consider making it `volatile`.
3. override the relevant `fireXXX()` methods to check the status of fireEvents
4. only set `fireEvents = true` after all construction and initialization is complete
5. if a "major overhaul" is later called for, such as on loading a new file, new settings, you can set fireEvents back to false while rebuilding everything.

Comment: -1 _when things are really convoluted_ it's mostly because the application code does something wrong. So instead of random indecent subclassing, whacky flags or muddying overrides, first step is to dig and understand what exactly goes wrong in the concrete context and fix _that_